# Unable to connect the bone to my mesh

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging, armature, rigify

I was following this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vzJ7454X46g&t=301s&ab_channel=TheGameDevCave and followed all the steps but can't figure out why my bone wasn't able to connect to my mesh.
Video demonstration:
[2024-01-15 23-52-14.mp4](https://cloudmails-my.sharepoint.com/:v:/g/personal/tp053611_mail_apu_edu_my/EaHampj4vF5BpN_pEEipb4UBrHGLbUpVS1MhU16IRZWonQ?nav=eyJyZWZlcnJhbEluZm8iOnsicmVmZXJyYWxBcHAiOiJPbmVEcml2ZUZvckJ1c2luZXNzIiwicmVmZXJyYWxBcHBQbGF0Zm9ybSI6IldlYiIsInJlZmVycmFsTW9kZSI6InZpZXciLCJyZWZlcnJhbFZpZXciOiJNeUZpbGVzTGlua0NvcHkifX0&e=kmVqhv)[image]

Comment: Please share your Blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page then edit your question here and paste the link into it. - I suspect you're trying to move your model with the FK>IK switch in the wrong position for the widgets you're trying to move.